# Flask: Handle catch all url different if path is directory or file

Tags: python, routes, flask

How can I make a catch all route, that only handles directories and one that handles files?

Below is a simple example

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/foo')
def foo_file():
    return 'Queried: foo file'

@app.route('/foo/')
def foo_dir():
    return 'Queried:  foo dir'

@app.route('/<path:path>')
def file(path):
    return 'Queried file: {0}'.format(path)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/<path:path>/')
def folder(path):
    return 'Queried folder: {0}'.format(path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

When I access `http:\\127.0.0.1:5000\foo` It calls `foo_file()` and for `http:\\127.0.0.1:5000\foo\` it calls `foo_dir()`. But querying `http:\\127.0.0.1:5000\bar` and `http:\\127.0.0.1:5000\bar\` both call
`file()`. How can I change that?

I know I can check the trailing slash and reroute manually, I was just wondering if there's another way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just do this...

```
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def catch_all(path):
    if path.endswith('/'):
        return handle_folder(path)
    else:
        return handle_file(path)
```

Comment: Thats what I'm ccurrently doing. I wss just thinking if there's a builtin way in Flask to do it.

Comment: I tried swapping the order of defining the file and folder functions in your original example, but then Flask redirects to force an ending slash. So I think this is the way to go - keep it simple.

Comment: Regarding ordering of routes see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25011800. Apparently Flask sorts the routes by length and variable content rather than using the order of declaration.