# Flask: why having path converter in root route doesn't work?

Tags: python, flask, url-routing, werkzeug

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/page/<path:page>')
def article(page):
    return render_template('page.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Work just fine. But if i change the second route to `@app.route('/<path:page>')`, then any access to URL like `/path/to/page` yields 404.

Why doesn't `@app.route('/<path:page>')` work?

Related questions, that don't answer the question however:

- [Flask: Handle catch all url different if path is directory or file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444769/flask-handle-catch-all-url-different-if-path-is-directory-or-file)
- [Custom routing in Flask app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19212980/custom-routing-in-flask-app)
- [Capture arbitrary path in Flask route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117416/flask-capturing-url-string-as-parameter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`static_url_path` conflicts with routing. Flask thinks that path after `/` is reserved for static files, therefore `path` converter didn't work. See: [URL routing conflicts for static files in Flask dev server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17135006/url-routing-conflicts-for-static-files-in-flask-dev-server)

Answer (score 1):

works flawless for me:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/page/<path:page>')
def article(page):
    return render_template('page.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

I can access: `http://localhost/` -> `index` and `http://localhost/page/<any index/path e.g.: 1>` -> `article`

Comment: `@app.route('/<path:page>')` also work, probably @sindikat, do not reload application.

Comment: The key difference is `static_url_path=''`.