# Are Python flask order of routes defined?

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I have a setup similar to the below in my views:

```
@app.route("/test")
def test():
    ...
@app.route("/<to>")
def page(to):
    ...
```

It seems that function test in the example always will be called when accessing the "/test" url. This is also what I want. But I cannot find this behavior in the documentation. Is it so that a defined name is always prioritized over a variable? Or is it the order of the definitions that counts? Can i set priorities in any way to make sure this will not break in the future?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Flask uses [Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/) to handle routing, and it orders routes based on how many variable parts are in the route.

`/test` has no variable parts, while `/<to>` *does*, so it'll try to match `/test` first.

Currently, ordering is done based on the [`Rule.match_compare_key()` function](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/routing.py#L1159-L1173), documented as:

```
def match_compare_key(self):
    """The match compare key for sorting.

    Current implementation:

    1.  rules without any arguments come first for performance
        reasons only as we expect them to match faster and some
        common ones usually don't have any arguments (index pages etc.)
    2.  The more complex rules come first so the second argument is the
        negative length of the number of weights.
    3.  lastly we order by the actual weights.

    :internal:
    """
```

Weights are determined by parts of the path being static (weighted more heavily than dynamic parts, with shorter paths being matched first), or by the converter specific weight (numeric converters are sorted before string-based converters, sorting before the arbitrary path converter).

Comment: I where to ask about weights, but saw your edit. Great answer!

Comment: Is this still the case? Any official word from the Flask authors to rely on? It still seems to be missing from the docs.